# Settings API - format container of setting and setting's description

Tags: plugin-development

This is how I create my settings page's output:

```
public function create_settings_page() {

    $this->options = $this->lal_get_settings();     

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>My plugin name</h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
            // Output nonce, action, and option_page fields for a settings page.
            settings_fields( 'lal_settingz' );
            do_settings_sections( $this->settings_page_name );
            submit_button();
        ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

All my settings appear within `tr` tags, `th` being setting description and `td` setting itself. I would like manipulate whole `tr`, for example apply `display: none` if other setting has certain value or wrap this `tr` with `div` and do the same with this `div` element.

With jQuery I am able to access `tr` as parent of parent of my setting element dynamically like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('#lal_display_type').change(function() {      
        if (this.value === 'icon') {
            $('#lal_login_text').parents().eq(1).hide();
        } else if (this.value === 'links') {
            $('#lal_login_text').parents().eq(1).show();
        }
    });

});
```

However, I would like to use PHP `style="display: none"` for initial display, to avoid any flickering on page load with jQuery solution, but I don't see any way to access mentioned `tr`. Should I replace `do_settings_sections` with some custom way to provide output of my settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to modify the `<tr>` tag, but for making it hidden by default (or initially hidden), then you can use the sixth parameter passed to `add_settings_field()`, which is [`$args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_field/#parameters):

```php
add_settings_field(
    'my_field',           // ID
    'My Field',           // Title
    'my_field_callback',  // Callback
    'my-setting-admin',   // Page/slug
    'setting_section_id', // Section
    array( 'class' => 'hidden' )
);
```

So as you can see, we set the `tr`'s `class` to `hidden` which applies `display: none` to the `tr` element. (`hidden` is an existing CSS rule in `wp-admin/css/common.css` which is loaded on the WordPress admin pages).